# Maximum update depth exceeded in React Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement a lazy loading in a MERN stack app like in [producthunt](https://producthunt.com). I want to have the posts created on the current date shown by default. If the user scroll down, it will fetch more data on the previous date. I am using react infinite scroll. However, it seems like the app requests to api like an infinite loop without listening on scrolling. I got the following error.
`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

The function is async/await so I don't understand why it keeps calling new requests even though the old request is not resolved yet.

In a Post components

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import UserItem from '../users/UserItem';
import TopDiscussion from '../TopDiscussion';
import SmallAbout from '../SmallAbout';
import { getPostsByDate } from '../../actions/post';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

const Posts = ({ getPostsByDate, post: { posts, loading } }) => {
  const now = new Date();
  const startOfToday = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate()
  );

  // startOfToday =  startOfToday -1
  useEffect(() => {
    getPostsByDate(startOfToday);
  }, [getPostsByDate]);

  const [date, setDate] = useState(startOfToday);
  const [shown, setShown] = useState();

  const getPosts = () => {
    getPostsByDate(date);
    let count = new Date(date);
    count.setDate(count.getDate() - 1);
    setDate(count);
  };

  return loading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <div className='main-grid'>
      <div className='posts-grid'>
        <h1 className='large text-primary'>Ideas</h1>
        <div className='posts'>
          <div className='post-dummy'>
            <InfiniteScroll
              dataLength={posts.length}
              pageStart={0}
              loadMore={getPosts}
              hasMore={posts && posts.length < 10}
              loader={
                <div className='loader' key={0}>
                  Loading ...
                </div>
              }
            >
              {posts
                .sort((a, b) =>
                  a.likes.length > b.likes.length
                    ? -1
                    : b.likes.length > a.likes.length
                    ? 1
                    : 0
                )
                .map(post => (
                  <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
                ))}
            </InfiniteScroll>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='right-panel-grid'>
        <SmallAbout />
        <UserItem />
        <TopDiscussion posts={posts} />
        <div
          className='fb-group'
          data-href='https://www.facebook.com/groups/ideatoshare/'
          data-width='350'
          data-show-social-context='true'
          data-show-metadata='false'
        ></div>

        <iframe
          title='producthunt'
          style={{ border: 'none' }}
          src='https://cards.producthunt.com/cards/posts/168618?v=1'
          width='350'
          height='405'
          frameBorder='0'
          scrolling='no'
          allowFullScreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Posts.propTypes = {
  getPostsByDate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPostsByDate }
)(Posts);
```

Post reducer

```
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  POST_ERROR,
  UPDATE_LIKES,
  UPDATE_LIKE,
  UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES,
  DELETE_POST,
  ADD_POST,
  GET_POST,
  ADD_COMMENT,
  REMOVE_COMMENT,
  ADD_SUB_COMMENT,
  REMOVE_SUB_COMMENT,
  UPDATE_STATUS
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  post: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, ...payload],
        // posts: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: payload,
        // posts: [payload, ...state.posts],
        loading: false
      };

    case POST_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };

    case UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: payload
        },
        loading: false
      };

    case UPDATE_LIKES:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id ? { ...post, likes: payload.likes } : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
    case UPDATE_LIKE:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: { ...state.post, likes: payload },
        loading: false
      };

    case UPDATE_STATUS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id ? { ...post, status: payload.status } : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };

    case DELETE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== payload),
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        // payload is all the comments
        post: { ...state.post, comments: payload },
        loading: false
      };

    case ADD_SUB_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        // payload is all the comments of a post
        post: { ...state.post, comments: payload },
        loading: false
      };

    case REMOVE_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: state.post.comments.filter(
            comment => comment._id !== payload
          ),
          loading: false
        }
      };

    case REMOVE_SUB_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: payload
          // comments: state.post.comments.map(comment =>
          //   {
          //   if (comment._id === payload.commentId) {
          //     comment.subComments.filter(
          //       subcomment => subcomment._id === payload.subcommentId
          //     );
          //   }
          // }
          // )
        },
        loading: false
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Post action

```
//GetTodayPost
export const getPostsByDate = date => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/posts/${date}`);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_POSTS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

post API

```
router.get('/:date', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const startOfToday = new Date(req.params.date);
    const endOfToday = new Date(req.params.date);
    endOfToday.setDate(endOfToday.getDate() + 1);
    const posts = await Post.find({
      date: { $gte: startOfToday, $lte: endOfToday }
    }).sort({
      date: -1
    });
    res.json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.send(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using an npm package for your InfiniteScroll element, or is it custom?  Either way, how is `loadMore` implemented?

Comment: Which InfiniteScroll package are you using? My guess is this happens because you call `getPostByDate` inside of `getPosts` and `getPostByDate` is listed as a dependency array for `useEffect`.. If you change the `[getPostByDate]` in `useEffect` to just `[]` does this still happen?

Comment: For those wondering, [this appears to be](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller) the package that is being used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I have updated your repo with a [working example](https://github.com/oze4/ideashare-react/blob/master/client/src/components/posts/Posts.js).. Your issue is that your API is not 'unlimited', as you claimed, and you ***do*** in fact need to check if all posts have been loaded or not.. Using the example I supplied along with the updates I made to your repo, you should be able to figure out things from here.

Ok.. so after some testing with `InfiniteScroll`, this appears to be happening because your `hasMore` property always equals `true`... You have to specify some type of condition so that `InfiniteScroll` knows when to, and when not to, load more data.

I got the same error as you before adding a check, which tells `InfiniteScroll` that there is no more data to load.

I have built the following example to show how to use `InfiniteScroll`

[You can view a live demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z1gdwu?embed=1&file=Components/PostsContainer.js)

---

**PostsContainer.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Posts from "./Posts";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

const loadingStyle = {
  textAlign: "center",
  fontSize: "48px",
  color: "red"
};

function PostsContainer({ url, itemsToDisplay = 5 }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [shownData, setShownData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let items = await fetchPosts(url);
      let itemsToShow = selectNItems(items, itemsToDisplay);
      setShownData(itemsToShow);
      setData(items);
    })();
  }, [url]);

  async function fetchPosts(url) {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
  }

  const selectNItems = (obj, n) => {
    return obj.slice(0, n);
  }

  const loadMorePosts = () => {
    let items =
      data &&
      shownData && 
      selectNItems(data, shownData.length + itemsToDisplay)
    setShownData(items);
  };

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      pageStart={0}
      loadMore={loadMorePosts}
      hasMore={data && shownData && data.length > shownData.length}
      loader={<div style={loadingStyle}>Loading ...</div>}
      useWindow={true}
    >
      <Posts posts={shownData} />
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
}

export default PostsContainer;
```

---

**Posts.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post';

const headingStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center',
}

function Posts({ posts }) {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1 style={headingStyle}>Posts</h1>
      {posts && posts.length > 0 && posts.map((p, i) => <Post key={i} data={p} index={i} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

---

**Post.js**

```
import React from "react";

const containerStyle = {
  border: "1px solid black",
  margin: "10px auto",
  maxWidth: "50vw",
  padding: '0px 10px 0px 0px'
};

const postHeaderStyle = {
  textAlign: "center",
  padding: "0px"
};

function Post({ data, index }) {
  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      {index !== "" && <h3 style={postHeaderStyle}>Post #{index}</h3>}
      <ul>
        <li>
          <b>userId:</b> {data.userId}
        </li>
        <li>
          <b>id:</b> {data.id}
        </li>
        <li>
          <b>title:</b> {data.title}
        </li>
        <li>
          <b>body:</b> {data.body}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

---

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import PostsContainer from "./Components/PostsContainer";

function App() {
  return (
    <PostsContainer
      itemsToDisplay={5}
      url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    />
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I tried to set the condition in `hasMore` like the following.  `hasMore={posts && posts.length < 10}` to test it out whether it would stop. However, the function still get calls even if the `posts.length` exceeds 10. posts is a state managed in redux. It looks like the `posts.length` does not get updated.

Comment: You're going to have to share more of your code and your redux setup for anyone to help. Can you update your post with the entire `Posts` component and some of your redux code? Sounds like the issue has to do with the fact you aren't tracking how many items are currently being shown versus total items. If you look through my `PostsContainer` component above, it shows how you have to track total items as well as shown items...

Comment: Thanks! I updated the post.  What I want to do is a little bit different than yours. You get all the data from the api in  `useEffect` hook. However, I only want the data each day like in [producthunt](https://producthunt.com) and ask for more on the previous dates if user scroll down. But I wonder how do you can do that. "load one more day if scroll? " Maybe you can use threshold option in the InfiniteScroll tag?

Comment: I also watched this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk_6BKiy6X4) and it somehow works even if the `hasMore` is set to `true`

Comment: I guess it all depends on whether or not you know if the API you're using has a limit or not.. For example, I know the API I'm using only has 100 posts.. I updated the StackBlitz demo to show how you can use Redux for this as well as call the API during `loadMore`. [You can find the demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z1gdwu?embed=1&file=Components/PostsContainer.js)..

Comment: i am about to crash but I will update my answer tomorrow with some Redux code and the updated Components from the StackBlitz.. You'd obviously want the `PostsContainer` to be a bit more flexible but I just wanted to show you how you could accomplish this for now..

Comment: thank you so much. I'm still trying to figure it out. the API will not have limit in my case.

Comment: What API are you using? Is it publicly available?

Comment: It's the last block of code I put in the post. It just takes data on a specific date from a database.

Comment: I don't see it specified anywhere. Oh well, good luck getting this fixed!

Comment: PostAPI is the api I'm using. Here is my [github page] (https://github.com/KittichoteKamalapirat/ideashare-react) for this app.
I am super stuck. `the getPostsByDate` keeps calling forever.

Comment: So you're not using a publicly available API.. It is your own API... that makes it nearly impossible for me to test this out.. also, by the way, I would add these files ([this](https://github.com/KittichoteKamalapirat/ideashare-react/blob/master/config/default.json) one and [this](https://github.com/KittichoteKamalapirat/ideashare-react/blob/master/config/production.json) one) to your `.gitignore`... You have the username and password for you mongo database just sitting in your repository...

Comment: @KittichoteChain I forked your repo and got things working. I updated my answer with a link... Not really sure what else you want... especially for no upvotes or anything! :)

Comment: HIghly sorry I forgot to upvote! Thanks for the info about gitignore.

Comment: that's true about the API that you can't test out. sorry again, I completely forgot about that fact.

Comment: @KittichoteChain I actually was able to test your API after forking your repo... It is EXTREMELY important to note that your Mongo username/password/connection string were just sitting in your repo, so anyone could log into your Mongo instance... To test, I just forked your repo and ran `npm run dev` to start both the front end and backend, which allowed me to test your API. Might want to change your password to be honest. Just removing it from the repo is not enough, as it will still be in your repos history.